# In Grails, how can I order eagerly fetched domain records?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Greetings, I would like to order eagerly fetched domain objects that another domain class owns in a 1:m relationship, but cannot figure how to do this. When I try with a simplified project, I get an error. Below are my attempts:

```
class Picture {
    String name

    static hasMany = [comments:Comment]
    static mapping = {
        comments(lazy:false, sort:'content', order:'desc')
    }
}

class Comment {
    String content
    Date dateCreated

    static belongsTo = [Picture]
}
```

Now, when testing how the record fetch with `println Picture.get(1) as JSON`, I get the following error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: COMMENTS0_.CONTENT in statement [select comments0_.picture_comments_id as picture1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment2_0_ from picture_comment comments0_ where comments0_.picture_comments_id=? order by comments0_.content desc`

Without `sort:'content', order:'desc'`, the Comments are in random order but no error.

Comment: if you write it like this: static mapping = { comments sort:'content', order:'desc' } without eager loading. does this not work ?

Comment: I had not tried that, but when I did, I still got the same SQLException as with my earlier.

Comment: I think you run into a known problem. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4089.

Comment: Well it does indeed look like my problem, I don't really understand the SQL statement completely because of the confusing table names. Should you answer and me select the answer as accepted or should we leave this question open?

Comment: please leave it open. I will search for a solution later on. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the ordering after the list of children was already fetched, at the time I need them in the code. Something like this:

```
def sortedComments = myPicture.comments.sort{it.content}.reverse()
```

Has the advantage of allowing unlimited sorting configurations as needed, as opposed to only one as retrieved by default.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution because it has been so long and there doesn't appear to be any other solutions. I don't know if this affects Grails 1.3.7 only and I don't have time to resarch. I used a solution very similar to this to go around the problem.